# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: java dont work in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When trying to run my class `Main` in Visual Studio Code I'm receiving the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Desktop\Desktop\code> c:; cd 'c:\Users\Desktop\Desktop\code'; & 'c:\Users\Desktop\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-@.34.@\scripts\launcher.bat' "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-16.@.1.9-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
"-cp' 'C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Roaming\Code\User \workspaceStorage\2a341cb828c3a967328459013f2df3df\ redhat . java\jdt_ws\code_d2af99d2\bin' "Main"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

at Main.main(first.java:2)
```

Code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68229546/2422776 ?

Comment: Hi Van, can you add code, you are trying to execute on VS?

Comment: That's the runtime error. But there is a compilation problem.  What is that?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in your error message

> PS C:\Users\Desktop\Desktop\code> c:; cd 'c:\Users\Desktop\Desktop\code'; & 'c:\Users\Desktop.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-@.34.@\scripts\launcher.bat' "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-16.@.1.9-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
> "-cp' 'C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Roaming\Code\User \workspaceStorage\2a341cb828c3a967328459013f2df3df\ redhat . java\jdt_ws\code_d2af99d2\bin' "Main"
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> at Main.main(**first.java**)

But your class is named

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

You have to rename the file to `Main.java`. The file and class name must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Unresolved compilation problem

This means you're trying to execute code that is not legal Java.

Somewhere earlier, you will have got an error message pointing out problems with the source program. That's the error you need to fix before trying to run it.